# shadow not showing in angular project

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, shadow

I just started using Angular and i'm trying to add shadow to a mat-card block, but it doesnt show up.

Here's the css:

```
.shadow { 
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 7px rgba(150, 70, 5, 5);
}
```

And where i'm trying to use it:

```
  <mat-card class="example-card shadow">
```

And nothing shows up.
Earlier today I tried this and it worked, but I had some problems adding bootstrap to my project so I took the L and restarted it, since it wasn't really complicated. But this specific thing doesn't work anymore. Could it be that I missed something needed to install? Some imports? I've no clue

Comment: Here's something weird guys, when I refresh the page the shadow only shows for like 1 sec then it disappears. Wtf?

Comment: You are probably including a stylesheet which overrides the `.shadow` class right after your block. That would explain the flickering you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably overriding the .shadow CSS from a stylesheet. So make box-shadow as important

```
.shadow { 
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 7px rgba(150, 70, 5, 5)!important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this worked! Thank you so much! 
Can you give me some more info about this overriding, maybe some links or keywords to search? Im curious what this is about and im not sure how to find it, as I said Im just learning!
Thanks again!

Comment: use [ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity ]